# Publish Android app to store using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

How can I publish an Android app to store in Visual Studio?

I see the Tools | Options | Publish Android App.

However, I need a tutorial on what to do with the fields that are provided.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions for [publishing a Xamarin.Android application](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/) on the [Xamarin developer portal](http://developer.xamarin.com/).

Specifically, [part 2](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#_Sign_the_APK_) covers the **Publish Android App** menuitem you mentioned. It's a little hard to see - but at the top-right of that page there is a 'switch' between XAMARIN STUDIO and VISUAL STUDIO instructions (click on Visual Studio to see the correct information and screenshots for your IDE).

[image: publish android app]